# Mongoose not creating indexes - auto expire document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, indexing, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to auto expire a document using this methods :

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        field: { type: String },
        expireAt: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now,
            index: { expires: '2m' }
        }
    },
    { timestamps: true, autoIndex: true }
);
```

But the document never expire, I tried different syntax, removing or adding "autoIndex" etc ... , but nothing will do. When checking indexes tab in Mongodb Compass I can clearly see the index created :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNlKE.png. However when checking in the mongo shell `db.myCollection.getIndexes()` I can see all previous indexes except the one "expireAt" I just created. I'm confused :I

Comment: If you're using mongo shell, have you switched to the correct database?

Comment: Yes all the queries 'db.oneCollection.find() etc ...' are giving me the correct documents, it matches what is seen in compass

Comment: Hmm, not sure then. I tested and it seems that both Compass and shell provide the correct indexes for me. The only one thing that I can suggest is to restart shell. In theory this shouldn't help but who knows.

Comment: Restarting didn't work, I ended up re-installing mongodb after fully uninstalling it and now everything works. Something I didn't mention is that at some point I converted this standalone instance to a replica set to try out the watch method, I probably did something wrong.